# how to fix "No wifi adapter found" issue in Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS

Tags: drivers

I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS as a dual OS along with windows 10, for some reason my wifi adapter is not being recognized in Ubuntu. In windows 10 the wifi adapter(USB) works fine and the light blinks but in Ubuntu the WiFi adapter(USB) is not recognized(no light). How do I fix this issue?

result of running command "lshw -C network":

```
*-network                 
      description: Ethernet interface
      product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
      vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:22:00.0
      logical name: enp34s0
      version: 15
      serial: 2c:f0:5d:89:0f:7c
      size: 1Gbit/s
      capacity: 1Gbit/s
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-53-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.41 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
      resources: irq:36 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcb04000-fcb04fff memory:fcb00000-fcb03fff
```

Out put of lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1532:0064 Razer USA, Ltd Razer Basilisk
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:012d TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0951:16bf Kingston Technology USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 214b:7250  USB2.0 HUB
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0d8c:0012 C-Media Electronics, Inc. USB Audio Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am using TP-link AC1300 USB adapter

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `lsusb`. Thanks.

Comment: I've posted an answer. Let us know, whether drivers from Cilynx's GitHub repo works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `Device ID` that you've posted:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:012d TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
```

you need `Realtek RTL8812BU` drivers for your TP-Link Archer T3U USB wireless adapter.

You can install the drivers from [Cilynx's GitHub repo for RTL88x2BU](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU).

As detailed in the repo, you can install the drivers using [DKMS installation](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU#dkms-installation) method:

```
git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git
cd rtl88x2bu
VER=$(sed -n 's/\PACKAGE_VERSION="\(.*\)"/\1/p' dkms.conf)
sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}
sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Edit:

Even after installing the drivers, if you get errors like:

`Activation of network connection failed or the system keep asking for password again and again,`

it's worth changing some of the router settings.

(1) If the `Wireless Network Mode` is on `Mixed/Auto`, you could try changing it to `N-only and/or AC-only`

(2) Try changing Wireless channel

(3) Set wireless security to `WPA2-PSK with AES`

Comment: thank you, now my wifi adapter is recognised and I can see available networks but I cannot connect to any network. When I enter the credential and try to connect, it keeps asking me for the credential again and again. When I try to connect to my mobile hotspot which does not require any password, it says "Activation of network connection Failed".

Comment: rebooted multiple times, still cannot connect to any network. Same error "Activation of network connection Failed"

Comment: @ss3 going through similar issues, it's worth checking few of the router settings. (1) is it `N-only/AC-only or Mixed/Auto` mode? (2) You could try changing `Wireless channel` (3) Set `Wireless security` to `WPA2-PSK with AES`. Thanks